# If only one record from row duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with record which I must record in my table. I want update row if product with same name exist.

```
if ((int)$price > 0) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM phones WHERE LOWER(`name`) = LOWER(?)";
    $duplicate = $this->db->query($query, array($name));
    if ($duplicate->num_rows() > 0) {
        $query = "update  phones (name,price,shop,link,photo,priority) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $this->db->query($query, array($name,$price,"Pigu.lt", $link, $photos, rand(0,1000)));
    } else {
        $query = "insert into phones (name,price,shop,link,photo,priority) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $this->db->query($query, array($name,$price,"Pigu.lt", $link, $photos, rand(0,1000)));
    }
}
```

table structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE `phones` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name`   varchar(500)
 COLLATE utf8_lithuanian_ci NOT NULL, `price` int(15)
  NOT NULL, `shop`  varchar(100) 
 COLLATE utf8_lithuanian_ci NOT NULL, `link` varchar(400)
 COLLATE utf8_lithuanian_ci NOT NULL, `photo` varchar(500) 
 COLLATE utf8_lithuanian_ci NOT NULL, `priority` int(5)
 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=544 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_lithuanian_ci;
```

at know code dont work, please help for this

Comment: SHouldn't it be `$duplicate->num_rows`, no `()`

Comment: it nothing changed, and why no () ?

Comment: in mysqli the num rows isnt a function, but a property, properties dont have `()`

Comment: it its mysql not mysqli

Comment: It looks like OO, and prepared statements. Pretty sure that doesn't exist in mysql

Comment: ok I removed, but its still error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the reason why your PHP doesn't work, but since you tagged your post with `mysql` and `sql` and not `php`, I assume you'll accept a SQL-centric solution.  Here are two; both assume that `name` is the primary key in table `phones`.

[ANSI-compliant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO phones (name, price, shop, link, photo, priority) \
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) \
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=?, shop=?, link=?, photo=?, priority=?";
$randnum = rand(0, 1000);
$this->db->query($query, array($name, $price, "Pigu.lt", $link, $photos, $randnum,
                               $price, "Pigu.lt", $link, $photos, $randnum));
```

[MySQL-only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO phones (name, price, shop, link, photo, priority) \
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$this->db->query($query, array($name, $price, "Pigu.lt", $link, $photos, rand(0,1000)));
```

Comment: name is not primary key.  and with this duplicate not working. Update question